# How to disable remove button for KryptonPage with context menu close item?

Tags: winforms, krypton-toolkit, krypton

How to block **KryptonPage for close** and i need to **remove button of docking area and context menu option for close**

i am using https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton
Visual Studio 2015 Community 
Win 10

There are details about my code for clear understanding

Following screenshot is Form designer about using controls 
[screenshot of Form designer using controls 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuN9l.png)

[screenshot of Form designer using controls 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PDkv.png)

Following screenshot of ruining application 
[application ruining  time for close menu item for block i want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjIog.png)

There are my form code c#

```
// this is main form code

public partial class frmMain : KryptonForm
{

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            kryptonPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            kryptonDockableWorkspace.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            kryptonPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            KryptonDockingWorkspace w = kryptonDockingManager.ManageWorkspace(kryptonDockableWorkspace);

            kryptonDockingManager.ManageControl(kryptonPanel, w);
            kryptonDockingManager.ManageFloating(this);


            kryptonDockingManager.AddDockspace("Control", DockingEdge.Left, new KryptonPage[] { NewWinTools() });
            kryptonDockingManager.AddDockspace("Control", DockingEdge.Bottom, new KryptonPage[] { NewWinTools(), NewWinTools(), NewWinTools(), NewWinTools() , NewWinTools() });

            kryptonDockingManager.AddToWorkspace("Workspace", new KryptonPage[] { NewWinControl() });


        }


        private KryptonPage NewPage(string name, int image, Control content)
        {
            // Create new page with title and image
            KryptonPage p = new KryptonPage();

            p.Text = name;
            p.TextTitle = name;
            p.TextDescription = name;
            p.ImageSmall = imageListSmall.Images[image];

            // Add the control for display inside the page
            content.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            p.Controls.Add(content);

            return p;
        }


        private KryptonPage NewWinControl()
        {
            UserControl1 br = new UserControl1();

            KryptonPage page = NewPage("New Tab", 0, br);

            page.ClearFlags(KryptonPageFlags.DockingAllowAutoHidden | KryptonPageFlags.DockingAllowDocked);

            return page;
        }

        private KryptonPage NewWinTools()
        {
            UserControl1 br = new UserControl1();

            KryptonPage page = NewPage("Tools 1 ", 2, br);
            page.ClearFlags( KryptonPageFlags.DockingAllowClose);

            return page;
        }

}
```

please help for block close  KryptonPage

Answer (score 1):

I have just come across the same issue.  I can see that this question was [answered here](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton/issues/197)

It looks like there is no way of actually removing the close button but you can intercept it and then ignore the event.

In the interest of completeness, this is the code you need to write:

```
private void CreateDockWorkspace()
{
    KryptonDockingWorkspace w = kryptonDockingManager.ManageWorkspace("Workspace", kryptonDockableWorkspace);
    kryptonDockingManager.ManageControl("Control", kryptonPanel, w);
    kryptonDockingManager.ManageFloating("Floating", this);

    kryptonDockingManager.AddToWorkspace("Workspace", new KryptonPage[] {
            NewPage("Overview"),
            NewPage("Main"),
            NewPage("Report"),
    });

    // This is where you wire up the CloseAction event handler
    var workspace = kryptonDockingManager.CellsWorkspace.FirstOrDefault();
    workspace.CloseAction += HandleTabCloseAction;
}

private void HandleTabCloseAction(object sender, CloseActionEventArgs e)
{
    // This event handler ignores the action
    e.Action = CloseButtonAction.None;
}

private KryptonPage NewPage(string name)
{
    var p = new KryptonPage();
    p.Text = name;
    p.TextTitle = name;
    p.TextDescription = name;

    content.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    p.Controls.Add(content);

    return p;
}
```